# Assign 3 random post to a category every day

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

i want to create a recipes of the day functionality.

Therefore i would like to add 3 wordpress posts with the custom post type "recipe" to a "reciepe of the day" category.

Also i would like to remove the recipes of the day from the previes day.

I already have a few lines of code for that, but i dont know how to assign and unasign a category there.

**TLDR: My problem:** I dont know how to assign and unassign a category to my loop.

```
add_action( 'wp', function () {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'mark_posts_as_featured_event' )) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'mark_posts_as_featured_event');
    }
} );

function mark_posts_as_featured_event_callback() {
    // if there are sticky posts in our CPT, unstick them
    $sticked_post_ids = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    if ( ! empty ) { 
        $old_featured_posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => '<MY_POST_TYPE>',
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'post__in' => $sticked_post_ids,
        ) );

        foreach ( $old_featured_post_ids as $post_id ) {
            // unassign category
        }
    }

    // stick new posts
    // get_random_posts
    $new_featured_post_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => '<MY_POST_TYPE>',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'fields' => 'ids',
    ) );

    foreach ( $new_featured_post_ids as $post_id ) {
        // assign category
    } 
}
add_action( 'mark_posts_as_featured_event', 'mark_posts_as_featured_event_callback' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for the

```
    wp_set_post_categories()
```

Function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_categories/

You can add the category 'daily recipies' for the day. 
Next day run a function use the same method as above and set the bool to 'true' and just add the recipies category.

This will then remove all post categories and only assign the ones you give it i.e. recepies.